# Justify html to right margin

Tags: html

I'm having trouble getting html text justified to the right margin (it's a right-to-left language). When I use the `text-align:right` attribute, it justifies the text only to the point defined by the `width` attribute (e.g., at 400pt from the left margin). How can I justify it to the right margin, without having the text extend all the way to the left margin?

Here's an example:

```
    </head><body><div style="width:400pt;line-height:125%;text-align:right" lang="he" dir="rtl"><bdo dir="rtl">ילח שדגחי שדחי שךלח דק לחי שדלחילחי לחדגי חליל ש דגחי  שדגחכילח שדגחי שדחי שךלח דקילח שדגחי שדחי שךלח דק לחי שדלחילחי לחדגי חליל ש דגחי  שדגחכילח שדגחי שדחי שךלח דקילח שדגחי שדחי שךלח דק לחי שדלחילחי לחדגי חליל ש דגחי  שדגחכילח שדגחי שדחי שךלח דקילח שדגחי שדחי שךלח דק לחי שדלחילחי לחדגי חליל ש דגחי  שדגחכילח שדגחי שדחי שךלח דק</bdo></div></body></head>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are wanting correctly, then you shoud replace

```
text-align: right;
```

with

```
float: right;
```

You can see what this looks like [here](http://jsbin.com/uxeyet/edit#preview).

By the way, why do you have a final kaf `ך` in the middle of the word `שךלח`?

Comment: @Dave Good. If this is what you need, you can accept it as your answer by pressing the check under the number. ;)

Comment: I will definitely accept the answer after the mandatory 7 minutes have elapsed. :)

Comment: Regarding the final kaf - this was random text meant to illustrate the problem. I hope you didn't read any deep meaning into it!

Comment: now I notice that if I begin the document with regular left-aligned English text, the "float:right" modification ceases to work!

Comment: @Dave you'd have to show me an example, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just realized there was some stray tags there that were messing things up. All is well now. :)